# What is wrong with my sorting function

Tags: c

I am having a hard time understanding why this sort function is not working.  It does put nodes into sorted order, but the first node is always lost in the process. Here is my code (the `head` variable is global):

```
void medianscore() {
   int i, j=0;
   int counter=0;
   struct student *curr=head;
   struct student *trail=head;
   struct student *temp=NULL;

   while (curr !=NULL)
   {
      curr=curr->next;    //couting the number of items I have in my list.
      counter++;          //this works fine.
   }

   curr=head->next;          // reseting the curr value for the 2nd position.

   for (i=0; i<counter; i++)
   {
      while (curr != NULL)
      {
          if (trail->grade > curr->grade)
          {
             temp=curr->next;      //bubble sort for the pointers.
             curr->next=trail;
             trail->next=temp;

             temp=curr;         //reseting trail and curr. curr gets back to be infront.
             curr=trail;
             trail=temp;

             if (j==0)   //i'm using j to determine the start of the loop so i won't loose the head pointer.
             {
                head=trail;
             }
          }
          j++;
          trail=curr;
          curr=curr->next;   //traversing thru the list. nested loop.
      }

      trail=head;
      curr=trail->next;
      curr->next=trail->next->next;  //traversing thru the list. outer loop.
      j=0;
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it systematic which node is deleted?  For example, is it always the node that is initially first or initially last that is lost?

Comment: it is always the first node

Answer (score 0):

Your node counting and use of variables `i` and `j` to control the sort has bad code smell.  These should not be necessary.

I'll address `j` and your head-of-list handling later.  With respect to the outer loop over `i`, you could instead maintain a flag for each iteration of the outer loop, so as to determine at the end of that iteration whether any swaps were made.  If not, then there is no need to perform another iteration.  This approach will never perform more iterations than your present technique performs, and for most inputs it will perform fewer.

The main problem I see in your code, however, is that it does not perform node swaps correctly.  Suppose you start with this situation ...

```
prev --> trail --> curr --> Z
```

....  You ask the question whether `trail` and `curr` must be swapped, and suppose you determine that they must be.  In that case you update `trail`'s `next` pointer and `curr`'s, but not `prev`'s, ending up with links looking like this:

```
prev ----V
       trail --> Z
curr ----^
```

At that point, `curr` has effectively been lost -- the chain of links from the list head to `Z` no longer passes through it, and nothing else you do fixes that.

I suppose you may have ended up with this problem in part because your head node is a special case, in that nothing links to it.  But that does not have to be.  Without changing anything about how the linked list is used elsewhere in the code, you can create a dummy node local to `medianscore()` that points to the head:

```
struct student dummy;

dummy->next = head;
```

You can then start each iteration of the outer loop with ...

```
trail = &dummy;
```

... and in the inner loop test whether `trail->next` should be swapped with `trail->next->next`.  Your loop termination condition and swaps would need to be a little different, of course, but you need always to have a pointer to the node preceding the first of the pair to swap, as this provides, so that you can update its `next` pointer.

And doing it that way has another bonus: the head node no longer needs any special treatment within the sort loop.  Instead, at the end you simply set `head = dummy->next;`.